# How to get the number of likes and dislikes on Drupal node comment?

Tags: drupal

I am a beginner in Drupal and I don't know how to count number of likes and dislikes on comments.

From which table can I found the number of like and dislike count in Drupal?

Answer (score 0):

The Drupal [Vote Up/Down](https://www.drupal.org/project/vote_up_down) module does exactly what you are asking.